# Orientation changes cause app to FC

Tags: android, orientation, saving-data, android-dialog, forceclose

I'm working on an app that scans barcodes, when it gets a successful scan it will show a Dialog with the code that was scanned and depending on what was contained within the bar/QR code it will show a button to open a browser, send an SMS, etc. While the Dialog is showing, if the screen changes orientation it crashes. I have got it working to where the orientation can change a couple times before it crashes, but when I check LogCat it says that a NullPointerException is causing the FC.  Before I had implemented @CommonsWare's suggestions I could get it to rotate an arbitrary amount of times before crashing, but since I've implemented them it FC's on the second orientation change always.  When I launch this in `debug mode` I can rotate the phone as many times as I want and as quickly as I want but as soon as I launch it in normal mode it always crashes.

Class Field:

```
private String currentType;
```

I implemented `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);    
    outState.putString("savedType", currentType);
}
```

Also `onRestoreInstanceState()`:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    currentType = savedInstanceState.getString("savedType");
}
```

---

### Update

---

I've updated the above code to what it currently is, following @CommonsWare's suggestions.  I've also edited my post for integrity.

I'm also using CM7 (Android Version - 2.3.7, Kernel Version - 2.6.37.6-cyanogenmod-g0799e00 android@portatile #1, Mod Version - CyanogenMod-7-11152011-NIGHTLY-N1, Build Number - GWK74).

Answer (score 1):

> In onPause() I have used this.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() to try to remedy that but it doesn't appear to have made a difference.

You do not call `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`. Android calls `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`.

> I guess it also seems to me that this should work, according to all the posts I've read about handling orientation changes.

You need to use better sources.

To attempt to repair your code:

Step #1: Delete the `android:configChanges` attribute from your `<activity>` in the manifest

Step #2: Delete your `onConfigurationChanged()` method

Step #3: Either move your `onResume()` logic into `onCreate()` to populate `currentType`, or do not attempt to use `currentType` before `onResume()`

Even better would be to replace your whole `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`/`getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` with `onSaveInstanceState()`/`onRestoreInstanceState()`, putting your `String` in the `Bundle`.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Rotation/RotationOne) demonstrating the use of `onSaveInstanceState()`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Rotation/RotationTwo) demonstrating the use of `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`.

Comment: For my sources I've been using StackOverflow, the Android Developer site and as many developer blogs as I could find.  If there are better sources for this then let me know.  As for your suggestions, they've been implemented and although it cleaned up my code a bit I'm still getting the same results, FC's after an arbitrary number of orientation changes.

Comment: @JustLikeThat: The Android Developer site did not tell you to write the code the way you have above. I suggest that you create a small sample project, get comfortable with `onSaveInstanceState()` and kin, then apply what you learned to your main project. You might also consider grabbing one of my free editions of [one of my books](http://commonsware.com/Android) (click on the Four-to-Free Guarantee tab) and reading the chapter on orientation changes.

Comment: No it didn't, but I was getting the same results as I am currently using what they had and then combined it with examples I saw here and in the blogs to see if that would change anything.  Implementing `onSaveInstanceState()` isn't beyond my grasp, but since I wasn't getting the results I wanted and was expecting I started to stray and get crazy with what I was implementing and how I was implementing it.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, then I implemented something similar to each of the examples you linked for me, and with each different one I can only change orientation once before it FC's on me instead of an arbitrary amount.  This project wasn't started by myself so I'm going to talk to the guy who started it and see if he can help.  I remember him saying they had to come up with a hack for the orientation of the camera while scanning for one reason or another and after everything I've tried I'm thinking that's playing a big part in whatever is happening with this.

Comment: @JustLikeThat: Ah, you said the magic word: camera. If you are using the `Camera` object, orientation changes get tricky. This is one of the few places where `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` makes sense, particularly in conjunction with something like `android:orientation="landscape"`. However, in that case, you don't need to do anything with `currentType`, because your activity is not destroyed and recreated, and so the data member will not be touched.